# check all the new numbers in a webpage python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use python 3.8.3.
I use selenium to control FireFox web browser.
I wrote a python script which load a web page , then login into an account .
this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://website')
userElm = browser.find_element_by_id('mail')
userElm.send_keys('USERNAME')
passElm= browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
passElm.send_keys('PASSWORD')
loginElm= browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.check-button')
loginElm.click()
gameElm=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#login-button')
gameElm.click()
```

up to here , this code login into website.
in the website, there are some numbers , you can see the Game in this website :

> https://www.bustabit.com/play

so as you can see, some numbers come up.
the class of numbers are :

```
text-right
```

what I want to do , is to ask the script to stay on page , and read all the numbers in the game (for ever) and save it into an excel file .
i dont know how to tell the script to monitor numbers and save them in excel file .
any help would be appreciated .

Comment: What kind of Bitcoin game is ? bet on up or down ?? put a print-screen with what you want. There are a lot o numbers :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is write a function that checks for new number ever X amount of seconds.

Example:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print("Checking for numbers...")
    # do your stuff
    s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```